# How is this recursive function working even though it is not being called?

Tags: c++, recursion

I am learning c++ and I am having trouble understanding this recursive method I will try to explain line by line

```
long factorial (long a)  

 
    {
      if (a > 1)
       return (a * factorial (a-1));
      else
       return (1);
    }
```

so here is my explanation

```
long factorial (long a)
```

this function returns a long a

```
if (a > 1)
           return (a * factorial (a-1));
```

so if `a` is `> 1` it returns `a` times `factorial (a-1)`  but `factorial (a-1)` is not a value.
I am a bit confused

Comment: In your question you say `factorial (a)` returns a `long`, but `factorial(a-1)` is not a value? Why should there be any difference?

Comment: Why do you think that the function isn't called? Doesn't `factorial (a - 1)` call the function?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz how is it called when it isn't complete? it has to use itself to complete itself but how does it  call it self if it isn't complete

Comment: @Syndromez Are you asking how a function calls a function in the middle of its execution? That's how functions are typically called. The function suspends its execution to invoke the other function, when the other function finishes, the calling function resumes. This works precisely the same way whether they're the same function code or not

Comment: why is factorial(a-1) not a value????

Comment: @Syndromez factorial(a) is not complete yet. What does that have to do with factorial(a-1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you call `factorial(2)` somewhere in the code. The following happens:

1. The `factorial` function is invoked with `a` equal to 2.
2. The function calls `factorial (a-1)`.
3. The current execution of `factorial` is suspended and a new instance executes.
4. In this instance, `a` is 1.
5. This instance returns `1` to the original instance.
6. The original instance resumes and returns 2.

If you call `factorial(3)`, the same thing happens with the outer instance getting `2` when it invokes `factorial (a-1)` and thus returning `3 * 2`, or 6.

(If you aren't familiar with proof by [mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction), you may not have enough of a math background. You can program without a sufficient math background, but it will be much harder and you will be very limited in what you can do.)

Answer (score 1):

Read about return values of functions. Basically, factorial (a-1) calculates the a-1th factorial, and then returns its value. Then, this returned value is multiplied by a.

Comment: ok I get what you mean. but how does it do the recursive factorial on the first value. like after the second value I get that it keeps going using the previous recursive calculation?

Comment: The first value is calculated when a=1 is fulfilled. In your code it sais that if a>1 is not satisfied, you will simply return 1. This means that you will not call he factorial function again.

Comment: Well, just as @Adelhart Programming said in his answer, each function call returns a value that is used to calculate the final answer. Factorial (6) would return 6*factorial(5), factorial(5) would return 5*factorial(4), and all the way until it reaches factorial(1), which is the terminating condition for the function. In the end, factorial(6) would return 6*5*4*3*2*1, or 720.